# Aptana Studio replace functions

Tags: replace, find, aptana, lines

I've been using Aptana Studio 3 for a few weeks now and I think it's somewhat ok.

One of the things that I miss from the code editor I used before (Macromedia Homesite: yeah, kinda old :P ) is the ability to find/replace text on multiple lines.

Is there a plugin that provides this?
Or is it possible to propose this feature to the developers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Daniele This feature is already requested to Aptana developer team .

Take a look at this link

[Enable multi-line search in find bar](http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-1507)

*Status : Open #Resolution: Unresolved*
This one adds support for multi-line find and replace in the find bar.

and also

[Via Tender: Multiline search](http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-432)

*Status:Open #Resolution: Unresolved*

Which adds a new multi-line search page to the existing set, with a few new options, taken from DreamWeaver and UltraEdit.[Please bring back the multiline search feature in aptana studio 2.0.x]

Now hope they Resolve this issues quickly.

Comment: Thank you, I hope this will be developed.